# How to invoke callback methods like @PreUpdate, @PrePersist, @PreRemove while doing bulk update, delete, insert in JPA 2.1?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, criteria, jpa-2.1

How to call a method annotated by `@PreUpdate` (including `@PrePersist`, `@PreRemove` and others) in JPA 2.1? Given the following `CriteriaUpdate` query as an example:

```
Brand brand=//... Populated by client. The client is JSF in this case.
byte[] bytes=//... Populated by client. The client is JSF in this case.

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<Brand>criteriaUpdate=criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(Brand.class);
Root<Brand> root = criteriaUpdate.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(Brand.class));

criteriaUpdate.set(root.get(Brand_.brandName), brand.getBrandName());
criteriaUpdate.set(root.get(Brand_.category), brand.getCategory());
criteriaUpdate.set(root.get(Brand_.brandImage), bytes);
criteriaUpdate.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root, brand));
entityManager.createQuery(criteriaUpdate).executeUpdate();
```

Given the method decorated by `@PreUpdate` in the associated entity - `Brand`.

```
@Column(name = "last_modified")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastModified;  //Getter and setter.


@PreUpdate
public void onUpdate() {
    lastModified = new Date();
    System.out.println("lastModified = "+lastModified);
}
```

This method is only invoked, when a row is updated using

```
entityManager.merge(brand);
```

How to invoke a method decorated by `@PreUpdate` (or `@PrePersist`, `@PreRemove`), when relevant operations involve the criteria API like `CriteraUpdate`?

Comment: You can't.  Criteria/JPQL bulk updates/deletes do not operate on the JPA entities, so they cannot trigger the entity callback methods.  You will need to query for the entities and then directly make the modifications to have the callbacks invoked.  Or incorporate the callbacks into your bulk update/delete statement

Comment: I did not get this statement, "*Or incorporate the callbacks into your bulk update/delete statement*". @Chris

Comment: Chris is right. Incorporate means to include the logic that you have in your @PreUpdate Java method in the criteria query (like setting some additional fields).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the entity to JPA. You're merely extracting the individual entity properties and passing them to JPA. In order to get the entity's `@PreUpdate` and friends invoked by JPA, you need to pass the whole entity to JPA, like as usual with `EntityManager#merge()`.

If that's not an option for some unclear reason (perhaps the entity is way too large and you'd like to skip unnecessary properties from being updated? in such case, consider splitting the entity over smaller `@OneToOne` relationships), then you'd need to **manually** invoke those methods on the entity before extracting and passing the entity's properties to JPA.

```
Brand brand = ...
brand.onUpdate();
byte[] bytes = ...

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
// ...
```